# Cannot destructure property 'latitude' of 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

So I'm currently watching NODE JS tutorials.the following content is about an simple weather application.

The weather application here seemed to work fine,but throws an error every time there's an invalid address.

The Code for fetching the weather data by coordinates fetched via the geo-location file(scroll down for the code)

```
const request=require('request')

const forecast = (latitude, longitude, callback) => {

  const url = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/35972b6a44cd0db6090786bed86c6ccc/'+encodeURIComponent(latitude)+','+encodeURIComponent(longitude)+'?units=si'

  request({url,json : true}, (error,{ body }) => {

    if(error){
      callback('Unable to connect to the weather service',undefined)
    }
    else if(body.error){
      callback('Unable to find location',undefined)
    }
    else {
      callback(undefined,{
        Today : body.daily.data[0].summary,
        CurrentTemperature : body.currently.temperature,
        ChanceOfRain : body.currently.precipProbability
      })
    }

  })


}

module.exports = forecast
```

and the code for converting the place name to coordinates

```
const request = require('request')


const geocode = (address,callback) => {

  const url ='https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/'+encodeURIComponent(address)+'.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWVjaHkiLCJhIjoiY2s0bDd6b2E4MGUzZjNuczh1ZngyZGFhNSJ9._ei4RZ_9ZUKJKK0xfqBj_A'
  request({url, json : true}, (error,{body}) => {

    if(error){
      callback('Unable to connect to the weather service',undefined)
    }
    else if(body.features.length===0){
      callback('Unable to find location',undefined)
    }
    else{
      callback(undefined, {
        location : body.features[0].place_name,
        longitude : body.features[0].center[0],
        latitude  : body.features[0].center[1]
      })


    }
  })
}

module.exports = geocode
```

and the application code itself

```
const geocode = require('./utils/geocode')
const forecast = require('./utils/forecast')

const address = process.argv[2]

if (!address) {
    console.log('Please provide an address')
} else {
    geocode(address, (error, { latitude, longitude, location }) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error)
        }

        forecast(latitude, longitude, (error, forecastData) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error)
            }

            console.log(location)
            console.log(forecastData)
        })
    })
}
```

I have also uploaded the error picture when i pass in a invalid address [ERROR PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LvQq.jpg)

I started learning NODEjs just a week ago,and i need some help.
and i hope this info is sufficient enough.

Comment: Notice in `geocode` that `callback` has `undefined` in the second argument for two error if statements. There is probably an error coming from there. Your error if statement is not catching that error because the destructuring is erroring beforehand. See below answer on how to resolve the destructure error, so you can see the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite specific. You are trying to access properties of an object that doesn't exist. JS is parsing the arguments of that function, and when you try to do something impossible, it throws an error.

You don't *have* to destructure here: just use an argument, check the argument isn't undefined, then destructure it if you want to after that.

Answer (score 1):

in geocode.js in both if and else if statements ,change statements as follows

```
callback('Unable to connect to the weather service',undefined || {})
```

Answer (score 0):

On file `geocode.js` on variable `url` try to replace `encodeURIComponent(address)` to be just `address`.

**From:**

```
const url ='https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/'+encodeURIComponent(address)+'.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWVjaHkiLCJhIjoiY2s0bDd6b2E4MGUzZjNuczh1ZngyZGFhNSJ9._ei4RZ_9ZUKJKK0xfqBj_A'
```

**To:**

```
const url ='https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/'+address+'.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWVjaHkiLCJhIjoiY2s0bDd6b2E4MGUzZjNuczh1ZngyZGFhNSJ9._ei4RZ_9ZUKJKK0xfqBj_A'
```

and on the main file. Try to passing the address like simple way on variable.

```
let address = 'jakarta'
```

After that try to re-run. I think it's works. Example Output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2EoQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

In geocode.js whenever an invalid address is passed,it returns undefined object as an argument.

```
if(error){
      callback('Unable to connect to the weather service',undefined)
    }
    else if(body.error){
      callback('Unable to find location',undefined)
    }
```

In app.js we are trying to destructure a undefined object,which is an error

```
geocode(address, (error, { latitude, longitude, location })
```

now this problem can be overcome by assigning an empty object as an default for the object.

```
geocode(address, (error, { latitude, longitude, location } ={})
```

so everytime the object is undefined,it becomes a empty object, therefore only the members of the object are undefined not the object itself which is not an error.